# Error displayed regarding JAVA_HOME path while running job from jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

While trying to run a job from jenkins (slave machine) , it gives me an error:

```
JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
```

I have checked the `JAVA_HOME` path for my system and its set to the correct location.
Java path on my machine: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`

I have also run a command from jenkins to get the java version and it is showing the correct version installed on the machine.

Exact error displayed on jenkins console:

```
java version "1.8.0_20" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_20-b26) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Error:

> JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.  JAVA_HOME =
>   "/usr/java/default"  Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your
>   environment to match the  location of your Java installation.
>
> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>   Collecting metadata... Metadata collection done. Email was triggered
>   for: Failure - Any Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any An attempt
>   to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored. Finished:
>   FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Ever since the JAVA_HOME is said to be "/usr/java/default", the problem is rather server-sided. /usr is a Linux directory.

Comment: Thanks for your Help DLIk !   Can you please help me to know how to export a variable in our job that sets JAVA_HOME to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Got The problem  resolved by setting java_home to  job configuration :

- Steps to set JAVA_HOME in your job configuration

  1.Click Configure 
  2.Under Build Trigger section
  3.Check "Inject environment variables to the build process " 
  4.Into Properties content : JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20 (user system jdk location )
  5.Save and apply changes.

For reference : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Move to environment variables in that particular VM, Set the Java_Home path correctly,
1. if there are two Java versions available select the JDK which has JRE inside it.
2. mention the Javapath\bin in the PATH variable of an environment variable

this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to define as a system property for the agent.